# Is it possible to make fluid borders in CSS? I'm drawing a triangle and I want it to cover 50% width and 50% height of the page.

Tags: css, border, fluid

Here's what Im using to make the triangle

```
#triangle-topright {
   width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 400px solid white; 
    border-right: 600px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    right:0; top:0;
    opacity: 0.24;

}
```

Ideally I want border-top: 50% height and border-right:50% width , but that doesn't exist so..
Is there a way to do this? Or am I better off using a vector triangle image and resizing it to 50%, 50%?

Comment: Oh no I CAN'T use a vector triangle/image over it because the overlapping div box makes the mouse events unrecognizable.
I have some major mouseover elements in the div below. But I want this white triangle as only an overlap. What can I use?
Should I make it just an img tag?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't explain it well but you can't make a non-rectangular shape using CSS `border`. A vector triangle or large transparent gif is your best bet. Alternative use a font with a triangle special character and make the font-size huge.

Comment: Thanks, I think vector triangle will be best then, because I want it to be fluid, exactly 50% height and width. Basically just wanted to know, generally, if we can set borders in %